# AVAudioPlayer Notification issue

Tags: avaudioplayer, avplayer

So I'm almost done with my app and I've hit a wall and cannot get around this final problem.

I basically have 2 view's.  A main page and the game play screen.

On the first play the game works fine, but when i leave the main screen and then return to the game screen all the sounds are duplicating and firing the the playerItemDidReachEnd early (because I'm guessing there are 2 instances of it, but it cannot seem to get the player to stop this. Here is the basic code causing this.  Any help would go a long way, thanks.  I'm not sure if my issue is i'm creating multiple instances of View2 in View1 or if I'm creating multiple player objects in view2 thus duplicating the notification.
I know there is a lot going on in my - (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification, but it works fine on the first load of the page, its only when I click "go back to view1" and then go back in to View2 that the issue happens.

```
View1ViewController.h
----------------------
#import "(i know here are arrows here, but can't make them show)UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ApplicationViewController.h"

@interface MonsterSpellViewController : UIViewController {
}
-(IBAction)showView1;

View2ViewController.m
----------------------
-(IBAction)showView2{

    ApplicationViewController *view2 = [[ApplicationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ApplicationViewController" bundle:nil];

    view2.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];

}



View2ViewController.h
------------------------
#import "(i know here are arrows here, but can't make them show)UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "(i know here are arrows here, but can't make them show)AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@class AVAudioPlayer;

@interface ApplicationViewController : UIViewController{

AVAudioPlayer *avPlayer;
}

View2ViewController.m
-------------------------
#import "View2ViewController.h"

@synthesize avPlayer;

-(AVAudioPlayer *)avPlayer {
    if(!avPlayer) avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]init];
    return avPlayer;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:)
     name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
     object:avPlayer];
}

-(IBAction)playSoundTest
{
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/monster3.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];

    [self.avPlayer play];
}

- (void)playerItemDidReachEnd:(NSNotification *)notification {
    //[player seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    if (playEscape == YES) {
        [self btnEscapeSound];
        playEscape = NO;
    }
    if ((startButton.hidden == NO) && (letterCount != -1) && (playFinal == YES))
    {
        [self btnFinalSound];
        playFinal = NO;
        playEscape = YES;
    }

    NSLog(@"Player Check accessed");
    if (letterCount == 3) {

        if (Winner == letterCount) {
            //moveNextSound = YES;
            if (intLoopCount < 104) 
            {
                if (intLoopCount<104) {


                    [self btnStartOver:intLoopCount];
                    playFinal = NO;
                    //intLoopCount++;
                }
                if (intLoopCount==104) {
                    startButton.hidden=NO;
                    playFinal = YES;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (letterCount == 4) {

        if (Winner == letterCount) {
            //moveNextSound = YES;
            if (intLoopCount < 105) 
            {
                [self btnStartOver:intLoopCount];
                //intLoopCount++;
                if (intLoopCount==105) {
                    startButton.hidden=NO;
                    playFinal = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }





}
}

-(IBAction)goBack:(id)sender{


    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [view2 release]; after [self presentModalViewController:view2 animated:YES];